# A function $f:I\times I\longrightarrow I$ continuous in each variable, where $I=[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:I\times I\longrightarrow I$ be continuous in each variable, where $I=[0,1]$.

Can we show there exists one point where the function is continuous?

Comment: Yes. It is continuous on $D\times [0,1]$ for some dense $G_\delta$ set $D$. Hint: Baire.

Comment: can you show me the detail or give me a book about the theorem

Comment: [Here is](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Separate_and_joint_continuity) more context.

Comment: it's helpful,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When we say that $f:I\times I\longrightarrow I$ is continuous we mean that for every $(x,y)\in I\times I$ is continuous

Comment: The question is about an $f$ that is separately continuous, for each $t\in [0,1]$, the function $s\mapsto f(s,t)$ is continuous, and for each $s$, the function $t\mapsto f(s,t)$ is continuous. $f$ is not supposed to be jointly continuous.